# how to edit the table during runtime in asp.net / How to insert a table inside a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am able to create an table (Normal table).. dynamically since the fields inside are dynamic.  Also it would be popped up during a button press event.

But I would need to design it inside a large textbox where the data inside the table must be editable.

Right now I am putting all the table details inside a div tag. And dynamically showing the data as

```
divTest.InnerHtml = str;
```

here str is of string.

Initially the table is put in this string using string buffer.
Later I used

```
 str = strbuffer.ToString();
```

I couldnt use textbox instead of divTest. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify [`contenteditable="true"`](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/) attribute for your div

Also post the div data back to a server using HiddenField set by javascript.

**.aspx Markup**

```
<div id="myDiv" contentEditable="true">Click here to Edit</div>

<asp:HiddenField Id="hdnDivData" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" OnClientClick="setDivContent();" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" />
```

In **JavaScript** for a button click event

```
function setDivContent()
{
 var divContent= document.getElementByID('myDiv').innerHTML;
 document.getElementByID('hdnDivData').value=divContent;
}
```

Server side **C#**

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string myDivContent= hdnDivData.Value;
}
```

***Note:*** Since you are passing a `HTML sting in post data` you need to disable the input request validation for your page. Otherwise you will get an error like `A potential dangerous request was detected` something like this.